# How to make PhpStorm suggest / autocomplete array keys

Tags: php, phpstorm

```
<?php


function test(){
    return array(
        'one' => 1,
        'two' => 2
    );
}

$test = test();

echo $test[''];
```

I would like to put my cursor in the last line in between the single quotes, and have it suggest `one` or `two`. How can I do this?

The below works fine, so why doesn't it work inside of a function:

```
    $test = array(
        'one' => 1,
        'two' => 2
    );



    echo $test[''];
// Suggests 'one' and 'two'
```

Comment: You can recommend it as a future feature on the JetBrains website?

Comment: @Martin I thought others would have had this request already, and I must be missing something. Why wouldn't this functionality be built in if it works with standard declared variables?

Comment: I don't know, but the place to get it built in is not Stack Overflow but the JetBrains product support forums, on their website.

Comment: That'd be pretty hard for PHPStorm to do since it would involve having to evaluate all your functions.  For this function it may seem easy, but what about functions that have arguments and dynamic arrays returned?

Comment: Please submit the request to JetBrains tracking system here: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WI#newissue=yes .

You will be able to receive the answer directly from our developers while other users will be able to write their opinion of your proposal.

Comment: 2nd case needs just parsing your code. 1st one needs parsing+executing code. IDE would work much much slower once it executed functions while editing code. Also as it was mentioned it would be impossible for slightly more complex functions...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> The below works fine, so why doesn't it work inside of a function:

Because it's implemented only for variables/class properties.

> How can I do this?

Just install **deep-assoc-completion** plugin. It can do even more than that (e.g. help with completion of array parameter -- what keys are possible (if you bother to describe those keys, of course) etc).

Comment: Brilliant, just what I was looking for! Thanks a lot

Comment: [Link to the plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9927-deep-assoc-completion)

Answer (score 2):

In newest PHPStorm versions you can achieve this through array shape. No external plugins are required.

```
/**
 * @return array{one: int, two: int}
 */
function test(): array {
  return [
    'one' => 1,
    'two' => 2
  ];
}

$test = test();

echo $test['one']; // Suggests 'one' and 'two'.
```